# How should I handle a file upload from iphone using media capture API

Tags: php, iphone, html, image-uploading

This is the html form i am trying to us to upload form an iPhone using media capture API:

```
<form action="processUpTests.php" method="post" name="capture" id="capture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="ImageFile" id="ImageFile" onchange="javascript:stabEagle();"/>
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" class="hiddenForm" />
    </form>
```

Submitting the form is done via this stabEagle():

```
function stabEagle(){
    $('#SubmitButton').click();
}
```

This is the processUpTests.php being used to achieve the goal:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{

    $DestinationDirectory = 'upload/'; //Upload Directory

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] array is not empty
    // "is_uploaded_file" Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something went wrong with Upload!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    //Let's use $ImageType variable to check whether uploaded file is supported.
    //We use PHP SWITCH statement to check valid image format, PHP SWITCH is similar to IF/ELSE statements 
    //suitable if we want to compare the a variable with many different values
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $type = "good";
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $type = "good";
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $type = "good";
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
    }

        $target_path = "upload/";

        //naming loop---------------------------------//
        $i = 9; //how many characters
        $prefix =""; //declares prefix var as a string
        $letters = ""; //declares letters var as string
        //execute loop
        for($e = 0; $e < $i; $e++){
            //random letter
            if($odd = $e%2){
            $prefix.= chr(rand(97,122));
            }
            //random number
            $prefix.= rand(0,9);    
        }
        $target_path = $target_path .$prefix. basename( $_FILES['ImageFile']['name']); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<img id='userImage' src='".$target_path."' style='max-width:310px'/>";


        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!<br/>";
            echo "<pre>".print_r($_FILES)."</pre>";
        }
```

It works when I use my computer to upload a photo. It does not work when I use my iPhone. I have an iPhone 5 with the latest OS for testing.

- Here is what my iPhone does:

I select the choose file option, it opens the menu to take a picture or choose existing image. I select the take picture option, my camera opens and I take a picture, I then select the use option and the form submits. On the processUpTests.php I get my error message "There was a problem uploading the file, please try again!". I am trying to print_r the $_files array and it outputs nothing. It seems like there is no file being sent to the server. Furthermore, there is no upload delay, the script outputs my error message instantly which leads me to believe that no file is being sent.

- Other conclusions:
  During my testing one of my scripts would upload the file and it worked as expected, One time only, then if I attempted to upload another file, it would simply skip the upload, and output the first image I took. The script was not too different from the below. If I deleted the image from the server, it would work again. Naturally this led me to believe that I could just upload to a different folder on the server, copy and rename the file to my uploads directory and unlink the original upload. I was wrong, it made no difference. It boiled down to one thing, I could use the script to take  picture and upload it one time, If I wanted to upload another picture, I must delete the previous one.

I am not sure if this helps anyone, but I thought it may be relevant. Then again, It could simply be syntax errors on my behalf.

Comment: You need to track the cause more down. Where is the first place in your script that does not work as expected? Don't start at the end, start at the beginning. Next thing is do some network sniffing, one-time for the browser where this works and one-time for the browser where this fails. Then provide the diff between those two network dumps so that it's clear where those two upload requests differ.

Comment: This is good. Thank you. I must admit that I am not familiar with the process of tracing the network activity. I usually use the web inspector in safari. Could I trouble you with your suggestion on what tool would be best for this. I will figure out the details of using from there.

Comment: Wireshark - http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use this method on my computer. I can not compare it with the iphone as I would need the software installed on there too which is not possible for me.

Comment: No, you don't need that. You only need to hook into the network, e.g. in the network where the server is.